# Pyside restore checkbox state from dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pyside

First of all I am very new to Python - this is my 2nd month of programming (only a few weeks with PySide/SQLAlchemy)so please be gentle.

I am developing a plant management app and have a form with a bunch of check boxes that relate to months of the year when seeds can be sown and another bunch of checkboxes representing planting zones.
I developed the form with QTDesigner.

I am collecting the object names and state of the check boxes and storing them in a dictionary (using the checkbox object name as the key, and the checkstate (true or fals) as the item) and then storing that in a sqlite db via sqlalchemy (using PickleType for the Column).

I want to read a record from the sqlite db and restore all the checkboxes to the state they were in when saved.

My problem is that the key from the dict (which is the checkbox object name) is a string.  I can't figure out how to map this to the checkbox.

For example dict will look something like this:

`{'zone5bCB': True, 'zone3aCB': False, 'zone7bCB': True, 'zone1CB': True, 'zone3bCB': False, 'zone2bCB': False, 'zone9aCB': False, 'zone4aCB': False, 'zone6aCB': False, 'zone10aCB': False, 'zone6bCB': False, 'zone10bCB': False, 'zone11CB': True, 'zone2aCB': True, 'zone8bCB': False, 'zone8aCB': False, 'zone4bCB': True, 'zone9bCB': True, 'zone7aCB': False, 'zone5aCB': True}`

Where the key is the object name.
So if I want to do this using the first key:item from the dict:

`self.zone5bCB.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)`

I've got the feeling I'd have to do a findchildren() match these to the object name in the dict somehow.  Or maybe I am going about this the wrong way altogether and I should store/restore the checkbox states in the database another way??

here's a very cut down version of what I have just showing the relevant methods from my GUI class:

```
def getCBState(self, wid):
    """ gets the state of all checkboxes on widget wid"""
    returndict = dict()
    CBs = wid.children()
    for box in CBs:
        if(isinstance(box, QtGui.QCheckBox)):
            returndict[box.objectname()] = box.isChecked()
    return returndict

def saveRecord(self):
    """ reads data from all editable widgets and saves to db"""
    # read checkboxes and store in dict's
    zonesdict = self.getCBState(self.layoutWidget2)
    sowseasondict = self.getCBState(self.layoutWidget7)          
    session = Session()
    newplant = PlantInfo(refname=self.refNameEdit.text(), 
                        botname = self.botNameEdit.text(),
                        zones = zonesdict,
                        sowseason = sowseasondict #saving dicts as Blobs
                        #lots more stuff is here but cut for this
                        )

def populateCBs(self, instance): 
    print(instance)
    if instance:
        for key, item in instance.items():
            if item:
                key.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked) #<-- doesn't work because key is string not a QCheckbox object

def displayDetails(self, current_id=0):
    """ Display records inthe detailed form"""
    session = Session()

    for instance in session.query(PlantInfo).filter(PlantInfo.id == current_id):
        self.clearAll()
        #populate gen info tab
        self.plantIdDisplay.setText(str(instance.id))
        self.plantNameHeader.setText(instance.botname)
        self.refNameEdit.setText(instance.refname)
        self.botNameEdit.setText(instance.botname)

        self.populateCBs(instance.zones)
        self.populateCBs(instance.sowseason)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about PySide or GUI code in general, but I think I can see two approaches that might make sense for you:

The first is to make a method that does the exact reverse of your current `getCBStates` method:

```
def setCBState(self, wid, statedict):
    """ sets the state of all checkboxes on widget wid"""
    CBs = wid.children()
    for box in CBs:
        if isinstance(box, QtGui.QCheckBox) and statedict[box.objectname()]:
            box.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

My other idea is based on your current `populateCBs` method, and it assumes that the object names in the dictionary correspond to attributes on the current object. It uses the `getattr` function to access the attributes:

```
def populateCBs(self, instance): 
    print(instance)
    if instance:
        for key, item in instance.items():
            if item:
                getattr(self, key).setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

I don't understand your code well enough to judge which of these approaches would be more appropriate for you, but I hope they'll point you in the right direction to find to something that will work.

Comment: Brilliant!  I tried both of your methods and they both worked.  Thanks very much, I was really stuck on this one.